# Nautilus/Firefox : force thumbnail preview for large files

Tags: nautilus, firefox

In the latest Ubuntu 18.04 (Gnome desktop), the file manager (Nautilus) lets the user to decide the maximum size of the files which thumbnails will be displayed. The value I set is the max allowed (4094 MB).

Unfortunately, when using the Firefox (v.61) file picker to upload pictures (which seems to use Nautilus),  I see the thumbnails previews only for pictures up to 2 MB or so.

As a photographer, some of my pictures blast easily 26 MB and I still need the previews. How can I enforce the thumbnails preview for large files ?

Comment: Seems to be impossible (as  Gtk FileChooser does not have such options in its [configuration schema](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gtk/blob/3.22.30/gtk/org.gtk.Settings.FileChooser.gschema.xml)). You can [open issue on GTK+ GitLab](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gtk/issues). Will drag-and-drop be a solution? Many filesharing sites support drag-and-drop capability.

Comment: This is ludicrous, how can that ever be possible? How can that be impossible? Who writes software that can't be configured even in the most basic way???